# restart service in rpm spec after config renamed

Tags: linux, package, installation, rpm, yum

I am writing an `RPM` spec file to install and update a daemon. I would like to ensure that any existing configuration files are appropriately renamed to `.rpmsave` `.rpmnew` during the update. For this I use `%config(noreplace)`, which appears to do the renaming correctly. Also, I have a command to perform a conditional restart in the `%post` hook, which works correctly as well.

The problem I have, is that when the `%post` hook executes, it seems that the config files have not been renamed yet, and this results in my service to fail to startup.

Is there an rpm hook that runs after the renaming, if not, what other approach can I take. I have considered using `rpm -V` to check if config file has been edited by the user and perform the renaming myself in the `%post`, but I dont really want to do this as it is reproducing the behaviour of `%config(noreplace)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the %posttrans hook  https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Packaging:Scriptlets. It should run at the end of the install.